# Calling js function on submit of form and prevent submission of form after completion of ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, bootstrap-modal

So i am trying to validate the form inside modal bootstrap 
This is the form

```
    <div id="extendWorkflowModal" class="modal fade" role='dialog'>
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 94%">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <header class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close Modal</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel" style="padding-left: 2%;">Select a block</h4>
      </header>
      <form id="wfpopup" onsubmit ='return addTasksPopUP();' method="post">
      <div class="modal-body">

          <%=render 'workflowpanel' %>
                <br />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="extendConfirmed">Add</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
      </div>
        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the function that is being called

```
function addTasksPopUP() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/timeline/addTaskPopup/' + engagement_id,
    data: $('#workflowpopup').serialize(),
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#thanks").html(msg)
      $('#extendWorkflowModal').modal('hide');
      $("#apd_success").show();
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("failure");
    }
  });

}
```

After the ajax request gets completed it seems the form is making a request with post method to url engagement/id but i want that form should make request with get method but  the problem is if i use get method then i get error Request-URI Too Large as the form contains many fields approx 50-60 so i am using method as post.Any advise will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ajax, it is not necessary to call ajax function on form onsubmit event.
Try to call ajax through 'onclick' event on 'id="extendConfirmed"'. It is enough.